# updating an html page with perl

Tags: html, perl, file, cgi

I am extremely new at perl and cgi and can't find this information anywhere on the web.

Can anyone give me an example on how I can pass information from an html document to a perl script and with that how to keep the script's contents consistent with what is on the page(like a registry).

Suppose I want to enter in someone's first and last name and submit it(or click a button). The first and last name should appear on the page while the information is passed to the perl script. Whenever the HTML page appears, the perl script that was last saved before will appear on the web page from the last use.

Note: I can only use html, cgi, and perl to do this. Is it possible with these three options? You can also refer me to someone else who asked this question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what are you describing is very well possible to do with CGI/perl. However it looks like you need to understand how CGI works, how parameters from HTML form are passed to back to server (and the CGI) and how to process them.

For introduction, look at [Perl and CGI Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm). The perl used in the article is quite old-school, but there is quite good overview on CGI architecture.